# SQL - Max Quantity Sold over 3 Day period

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to determine what was the max quantity sold over a 3 day period during a daterange. The User would supply the date range (in this example we have values ranging from 2015-03-30 to 2015-04-05) and we want to know the maximum sold over any given 3 day period during that date range for all products sold during that date range.

With the values below we can see that there is a Daterange of 3-30 to 4-1 for Shirt Medium that sold 8 items, a daterange of 3-31 to 4-2 for Shirt Medium that sold 6 items, a range of 4-1 to 4-3 for Shirt Medium that sold 3...etc

The max sold during any given period for Shirt Medium would then be 8.

```
CREATE TABLE #SalesDataTest ( Product NVARCHAR(MAX), Quantity INT, DateSold DATE);
INSERT #SalesDataTEST VALUES 
  ('Shirt Medium', 1, '2015-03-30')
, ('Shirt Medium', 1, '2015-03-30')
, ('Shirt Medium', 2, '2015-03-31')
, ('Shirt Medium', 1, '2015-03-31')
, ('Pants Large', 1, '2015-03-31')
, ('Shirt Medium', 2, '2015-03-31')
, ('Pants Large', 1, '2015-03-31')
, ('Shirt Medium', 1, '2015-04-01')
, ('Shirt Medium', 2, '2015-04-03')
, ('Shirt Medium', 1, '2015-04-05')
, ('Pants Large', 1, '2015-03-30')
, ('Pants Medium', 2, '2015-03-31')
, ('Pants Small', 5, '2015-03-31')
```

What I would like to see for results is

```
--Product--     --Max sold 3 day Window--
'Pants Small'   5
'Pants Medium'  2
'Pants Large'   3
'Shirt Medium'  8
```

Bonus if we can include the Start Date and End Date of the best 3 day sales window for each product.

Comment: your data set has `('Pants Small', 1,` but you expect to get **5**?

Comment: This is SQL-server code not MySQL.. MySQL doesnt support NVARCHAR(MAX) Please correct the tags

Comment: @Alex Sorry, corrected the data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland good catch. Corrected the tag. Thanks.

Comment: your data set has `Shirt Medium`  **8** but you expect to get **6**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long but working :)

```
declare @SalesDataTest table (Product nvarchar(max), Quantity int, DateSold date);
insert @SalesDataTest values 
    ('Shirt Medium' , 1 , '2015-03-30'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 1 , '2015-03-30'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 2 , '2015-03-31'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 1 , '2015-03-31'),
    ('Pants Large'  , 1 , '2015-03-31'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 2 , '2015-03-31'),
    ('Pants Large'  , 1 , '2015-03-31'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 1 , '2015-04-01'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 2 , '2015-04-03'),
    ('Shirt Medium' , 1 , '2015-04-05'),
    ('Pants Large'  , 1 , '2015-03-30'),
    ('Pants Medium' , 2 , '2015-03-31'),
    ('Pants Small'  , 5 , '2015-03-31');

declare @MinDate date;
declare @DateDiff int;

select 
    @MinDate  = min(DateSold),
    @DateDiff = datediff(day, min(DateSold), max(DateSold)) 
from 
    @SalesDataTest;    

with Numbers as 
(
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)    
),
Dates as
( 
    select top (@DateDiff + 1)
        CalendarDate = dateadd(day, row_number() over(order by (select 1)) - 1, @MinDate)
    from 
        Numbers n1, Numbers n2, Numbers n3
),
Products as
(
    select distinct
        Product
    from
        @SalesDataTest
),
NormalizedData as 
(
    select
        CalendarDate,
        p.Product,
        Quantity = sum(isnull(Quantity, 0))    
    from 
        Dates d cross join Products p  
        left join @SalesDataTest sdt on sdt.DateSold = d.CalendarDate and sdt.Product = p.Product
    group by
        CalendarDate,
        p.Product
), 
AggregatedData as
(
    select 
        Product,
        FirstDate = CalendarDate,        
        QuantitySum = Quantity 
                    + isnull(Lead(Quantity, 1) over( partition by Product order by CalendarDate) ,0)
                    + isnull(Lead(Quantity, 2) over( partition by Product order by CalendarDate) ,0)
    from 
        NormalizedData
)
select top 1 with ties
    Product,
    FirstDate,
    SecondDate = dateadd(day, 1, FirstDate), 
    ThirdDate = dateadd(day, 2, FirstDate), 
    QuantitySum
from 
    AggregatedData 
order by
    row_number() over(partition by Product order by QuantitySum desc);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Converted it over for my actual table/dataset and everything is working. Thank you very much. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome! Be just aware that such a chain of CTE looks good but may have performance issues for a lot of data. A better solution may be a series of intermediate temporary tables with proper indexes.

Comment: Good call, I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50a0a/10

```
SELECT Product, SUM(Quantity)
FROM SalesDataTest
WHERE DateSold BETWEEN '2015-03-30' AND '2015-04-01'
GROUP BY Product
```

Comment: Sorry @Alex. Maybe I'm wording it poorly. The goal is to determine which 3 consecutive days had the most sold product. Your query would just tell me how many were sold during that specific 3 day range, not telling me which 3 day subset of a larger range was the best.